# Issue with a basic elasticsearch "terms" query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a simple elasticsearch terms query as follows (using the sense chrome extension):

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
      "terms": {
         "childcareTypes": [
            "SHARED_CHARGE",
            "OUT_OF_SCHOOL"
         ],
         "minimum_match": 2
      }
   }
}
```

This returns 0 hits:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

I am not sure why because a match_all query does show that the two of the three records match:

```
GET _search
{
   "query": {
    "match_all": {}
   }
}
```

yields:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "bignibou",
            "_type": "advertisement",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "childcareWorkerType": "AUXILIAIRE_PARENTALE",
               "childcareTypes": [
                  "SHARED_CHARGE",
                  "OUT_OF_SCHOOL"
               ],
               "giveBath": "YES"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "bignibou",
            "_type": "advertisement",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 2,
               "childcareWorkerType": "AUXILIAIRE_PARENTALE",
               "childcareTypes": [
                  "SHARED_CHARGE",
                  "OUT_OF_SCHOOL"
               ],
               "giveBath": "EMPTY"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "bignibou",
            "_type": "advertisement",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 3,
               "childcareWorkerType": "AUXILIAIRE_PARENTALE",
               "childcareTypes": [
                  "SHARED_CHARGE"
               ],
               "giveBath": "YES"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and my mapping does show that the field childcareTypes is analyzed:

```
{
  "advertisement": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long",
        "store": "yes"
      },
      "childcareWorkerType": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "analyzed"
      },
      "childcareTypes": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "analyzed"
      },
      "giveBath": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain **why my terms query returns 0 hits?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and my mapping does show that the field childcareTypes is analyzed:

This is exactly where your problem is : the field is analyzed, however, a `terms` query look directly for terms, which are **not analyzed** (see [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query)).

To be more precise, the indexed values look like this :

```
shared_charge
out_of_school
```

And your `terms` query search for :

```
SHARED_CHARGE
OUT_OF_SCHOOL
```

You can check this behavior as if you try this query...

```
POST /bignibou/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "childcareTypes": [
        "shared_charge",
        "out_of_school"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

...you will find your docs.

You should either use your previous query on a `not_analyzed` version of the field, or a query from the `match` family.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for your replies. I would have marked both as accepted if this had been possible...

Answer (score 3):

It happens like that because `terms` will not analyze the input. This means that it will search exactly for `SHARED_CHARGE` and `OUT_OF_SCHOOL` (capital letters). Whereas you have that field as `"index": "analyzed"` which means ES will use the `standard` analyzer to index the data.

For `SHARED_CHARGE` ES stores `shared_charge`.
For `OUT_OF_SCHOOL` ES stores `out_of_school`.